# SELinux Write access for vsftpd and samba

Tags: centos, samba, selinux, vsftpd

This should be easy enough I think, but I'm new to SELinux.
I have a CentOS 6 file server. I have some LVM file systems at /var/media and I want to use both Samba and FTP to share them with a Windows machine. I am using ACLs so that permissions work nicely in Windows (I have a two user network). I've found that Samba, though working, is slow for file transfers, so I wanted to try FTP.

I'd like to keep using SELinux to keep things secure, but I'm running into trouble with accessing the files over FTP. I can read the files and write to my home directory. But I **cannot write to files in /var/media** (with the samba_share_t context).

I thought that `allow_ftpd_use_cifs` was supposed to handle that. I can get it to work with `allow_ftpd_full_access`, but I'd prefer to avoid this. What am I missing?

Here is the relevant info:

```
[mdurak@srv ~]$ ls -Z /var/media
drwxrwxr-x+ mdurak admins system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 docs
drwxrwxr-x+ mdurak admins system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 library
drwxrwxr-x+ mdurak admins system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 photos
drwxrwxr-x+ mdurak admins system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 projects

[mdurak@srv ~]$ sudo semanage boolean -l | grep ftp
ftp_home_dir                   (on   ,   on)  Allow ftp to read and write files in the user home directories
tftp_anon_write                (off  ,  off)  Allow tftp to modify public files used for public file transfer services.
allow_ftpd_full_access         (off  ,  off)  Allow ftp servers to login to local users and read/write all files on the system, governed by DAC.
allow_ftpd_use_cifs            (on   ,   on)  Allow ftp servers to use cifs used for public file transfer services.
allow_ftpd_use_nfs             (off  ,  off)  Allow ftp servers to use nfs used for public file transfer services.
allow_ftpd_anon_write          (on   ,   on)  Allow ftp servers to upload files,  used for public file transfer services. Directories must be labeled public_content_rw_t.
ftpd_use_passive_mode          (off  ,  off)  Allow ftp servers to use bind to all unreserved ports for passive mode
ftpd_connect_db                (off  ,  off)  Allow ftp servers to use connect to mysql database
httpd_enable_ftp_server        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to act as a FTP server by listening on the ftp port.

[mdurak@srv ~]$ sudo semanage boolean -l | grep samba
samba_domain_controller        (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to act as the domain controller, add users, groups and change passwords.
samba_portmapper               (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to act as a portmapper
samba_enable_home_dirs         (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to share users home directories.
samba_export_all_ro            (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to share any file/directory read only.
samba_export_all_rw            (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to share any file/directory read/write.
use_samba_home_dirs            (off  ,  off)  Support SAMBA home directories
samba_create_home_dirs         (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to create new home directories (e.g. via PAM)
cdrecord_read_content          (off  ,  off)  Allow cdrecord to read various content. nfs, samba, removable devices, user temp and untrusted content files
allow_smbd_anon_write          (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to modify public files used for public file transfer services.  Files/Directories must be labeled public_content_rw_t.
samba_share_fusefs             (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to export ntfs/fusefs volumes.
samba_share_nfs                (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to export NFS volumes.
samba_run_unconfined           (off  ,  off)  Allow samba to run unconfined scripts
sanlock_use_samba              (off  ,  off)  Allow sanlock to manage cifs files
virt_us
```

e_samba                 (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to manage cifs files

/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
# mdurak is in the chroot_list
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=YES
local_root=/var/media
```

Attempt in FTP to make the directory (there is also a denied message in the audit log so I know it's an SELinux problem).

```
Command:    CWD /var/media/library/music
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    MKD sdff
Response:   550 Create directory operation failed.
Command:    MKD /var/media/library/music/sdff
Response:   550 Create directory operation failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out from this: http://selinuxproject.org/page/SambaRecipes

Had to set the folder contexts to `public_content_rw_t` and do

```
setsebool -P allow_smbd_anon_write=1
```

Now I can write via Samba and FTP (and it will be easy to support other domains later)